# Trouble iterating a function with one input and two outputs on Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've created a function (name it MyFunction) which, given a matrix A, outputs two matrices B and C i.e. [B C] = MyFunction(A).

I'm trying to create another function which, when given a matrix A, will calculate MyFunction(A) and then calculate MyFunction(B) = [D E] and MyFunction(C) = [F G], and then calculate MyFunction(D), MyFunction(E), MyFunction(F) and MyFunction(G), and so on, until the matrices it outputs start to repeat. I know this process necessarily terminates.

I'm really having difficulty constructing this code. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  What part of it doesn't seem to be working?  Do you need to save the output of every step?

Comment: So you're trying to find matrix fixed points of your function?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)

Comment: My function takes a matrix A and outputs its 'cousins' B and C. I'd like to find A's cousins, their cousins etc

Comment: fixed point is A=f(A). Looks more like limit cycle (but not quite the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** rewritten wrong alg

```
function [list] = newFunction(A)   % returns all matrix generated matrix

list{1}=A;

done=0;
ii = 1;

while(~done)
    [B C] = myFunction(list{ii});
    list = list{list{:}, B, C};

    for jj=1:numel(list)-2
       if(all(all(list{jj}==B)) || all(all(list{jj}==C)))
           done = 1;
       end
    end

    ii=ii+1;
end

end
```

**UPDATE:** a more general way to handle an unknown number of outputs is to modify `myFunction` so that it outputs all matrices within a single cell vector. This way you can concatenate list this way:

```
[newMat] = myFunctions(list{ii}); % where newMat={B,C,...}
list = {list{:}, newMat{:}}; % or list=cat(2,list,newMat)

for jj=1:numel(list)-numel(newMat)
    for nn=1:numel(newMat) % checking for repetitions
        if(all(all(list{jj}==newMat{nn})))
            done=1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: He doesn't have all the matrices up front, they're generated by the function call.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. What's the easiest way to modify this if instead myFunction outputs either 0, 1, 2 or 3 matrices?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is binary tree recursion.  It's hard to give a good solution without knowing more about the problem, especially without knowing what you want as the output of this process.

I whipped this up to give an example of how you could do this.  It's not necessarily the most efficient because it stores all of the results at every step.  Given an input matrix A, it calculates a 2-output function `[B, C] = MyFunction(A)` and looks for either `isequal(A, B)` or `isequal(A, C)`.  When that occurs, it outputs the depth of the tree at that point, i.e. how many iterations had to occur before there was a repetition.  The bit with global variables is just so that I could do a simple example with an easy fixed point (the k'th iteration is just A^k).  It will iterate a maximum of 10 times.

```
function depth = myRecursor(A)

global A_orig;
A_orig = A;

depth = 1;
max_depth = 10;

pvs_level = cell(1);
pvs_level{1} = A;


while depth < max_depth,
    this_level = cell(2*length(pvs_level), 1);     
    for ix = 1 : length(pvs_level),
        [B, C] = MyFunction(pvs_level{ix})
        if isequal(B, A) || isequal(C, A),
            return;
        end
        this_level{2*ix - 1} = B;
        this_level{2*ix} = C;
    end
    depth = depth + 1;
    pvs_level = this_level;
end

function [B, C] = MyFunction(A)

global A_orig;

B = A_orig*A;
C = 2*A;
```

So, for example `myRecursor(eye(2))` gives 1 (duh) and `myRecursor([0 1; 1 0])` gives 2.

Comment: Thanks - this appears to me more advanced than I'm used to. Might take me a little while to get my head round it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use cells:

```
function [B]=Myfunction(A)
  B=cell(1,numel(A)*2);
  for n=1:numel(A)
    B{n}=func1(A{n}) %%% put some processing here
    B{numel(A)+n}=func2(A{n})  %%% put some other processing here
  end
end
```

Comment: Okay, I've edited my MyFunction code to output a cell array as opposed to a vector. My main problem though is how conceptually to construct a  program to iterate MyFunction on all of its outputs

Comment: You should be able to iterate on it using cells, no?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I'm new to Matlab (/coding in general)